# OR condition for Elastic search

Tags: php, elasticsearch

i am trying to find results based on OR condition with geo_point and sort by distance. I have posted here code which i tried for OR condition. This shows me error **No query registered for [should]**

```
{
"query": {
"filtered": {
  "filter": {
    "geo_distance": {
      "distance": "5000km",
      "location": {
        "lat": 28.613939,
        "lon": 77.209021
      }
    },
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "maincat_id": "55b2326501fcff8a338b4569"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}}}
```

but its shows me error [geo_distance] query does not support [bool]
please help me to solve it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this ?

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "geo_distance": {
                "distance": "5000km",
                "location": {
                  "lat": 28.613939,
                  "lon": 77.209021
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "maincat_id": "55b2326501fcff8a338b4569"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "maincat_id": "55b2326501fcff8a338b4578"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "maincat_id": "567a47e801fcff55228b4567"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, mostly done but when i add second term
"term": {
                "maincat_id": "55b2326501fcff8a338b4578"
              },
"term": {
                "maincat_id": "567a47e801fcff55228b4567"
              }

its overwrite the first one.....please help thanks